# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line X Error inflating class Y

Tags: android

I am getting 3 different crashes on Crashlytics. The crashes are appearing on both Android 4 and 5. Also there is no spesific device. The following 3 crashes don't appear all the time, in fact only 6 different users experienced them (among +1M user)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.appname/com.company.appname.activity.campaigns.CampaignDetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

-

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.appname/com.company.appname.activity.disclaimer.DisclaimerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
```

-

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.appname/com.company.appname.activity.login.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class com.company.appname.ui.widget.GEditText
```

As other answers suggested I checked memory, triple checked layout xml files, looked Manifest and Styles, but the problem persists.

Any suggestions?

Stacktrace of the first crash

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.appname/com.company.appname.activity.campaigns.CampaignDetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3149)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4262)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4334)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:440)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2358)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(SourceFile:356)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:226)
       at com.company.appname.activity.campaigns.CampaignDetailActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:119)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4262)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4334)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:440)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2358)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(SourceFile:356)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:226)
       at com.company.appname.activity.campaigns.CampaignDetailActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:119)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
       at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.(ActionBarView.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4262)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4334)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:440)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2358)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(SourceFile:356)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:226)
       at com.company.appname.activity.campaigns.CampaignDetailActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:119)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
       at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.(ActionBarView.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4262)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4334)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:440)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2358)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(SourceFile:356)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:226)
       at com.company.appname.activity.campaigns.CampaignDetailActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:119)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File .xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02018f
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3984)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3852)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:776)
       at android.view.View.(View.java)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
       at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.(ActionBarView.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4262)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4334)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:440)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2358)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(SourceFile:356)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:226)
       at com.company.appname.activity.campaigns.CampaignDetailActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:119)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: int[] cannot be cast to android.util.LongSparseArray
       at android.content.res.Resources.getRCCachedDrawable(Resources.java:3869)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3774)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:776)
       at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
       at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1192)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1086)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3968)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3852)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:776)
       at android.view.View.(View.java)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
```

Stacktrace of the second crash

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.appname/com.company.appname.activity.disclaimer.DisclaimerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseBonusActivity.setGBContentView(SourceFile:366)
       at com.company.appname.activity.disclaimer.DisclaimerActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:50)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseBonusActivity.setGBContentView(SourceFile:366)
       at com.company.appname.activity.disclaimer.DisclaimerActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:50)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
Caused by android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.webview
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getFactoryClass(WebViewFactory.java:161)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:101)
       at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2185)
       at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2180)
       at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2239)
       at android.view.View.(View.java)
       at android.view.View.(View.java)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java)
       at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.(AbsoluteLayout.java)
       at android.webkit.WebView.(WebView.java)
       at android.webkit.WebView.(WebView.java)
       at android.webkit.WebView.(WebView.java)
       at android.webkit.WebView.(WebView.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseBonusActivity.setGBContentView(SourceFile:366)
       at com.company.appname.activity.disclaimer.DisclaimerActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:50)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
Caused by android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.webview
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:114)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getFactoryClass(WebViewFactory.java:133)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:101)
       at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2185)
       at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2180)
       at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2239)
       at android.view.View.(View.java)
       at android.view.View.(View.java)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java)
       at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.(AbsoluteLayout.java)
       at android.webkit.WebView.(WebView.java)
       at android.webkit.WebView.(WebView.java)
       at android.webkit.WebView.(WebView.java)
       at android.webkit.WebView.(WebView.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at com.company.appname.activity.base.BaseBonusActivity.setGBContentView(SourceFile:366)
       at com.company.appname.activity.disclaimer.DisclaimerActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:50)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
```

Comment: Post the complete stack traces. The source of your difficulty usually will be explained in there.

Comment: @CommonsWare oops, sorry to forget that.

Comment: That one seems to be a problem with the Android System WebView package not being available (`android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.webview`). I don't really know how that gets hooked into the Android SDK. Perhaps while that package is being upgraded in the background, you can get this error. I doubt that there is much you can do about that.

Comment: @CommonsWare For the webview crash you are probably right, because it really seems a rare case. Could you also check for the first one? It seems there is a NotFoundException for a drawable. However that image is presented for hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. Also the size and the resolutions of that particular image is quite small, so I don't  think it will cause a memory related issue.

Comment: That one is strange. I agree that it's not a memory issue. However, you cite "size and resolution", but this is an XML drawable, particularly a `StateListDrawable`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File .xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02018f - I searched for 0x7f02018f and it was the name of a png file, that is why I cite size and resolution

Comment: Bear in mind that resource IDs can change on every build, so unless you are looking at the resources packaged in version of the APK that this user was using, you may be looking at the wrong resource.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for pointing that out, you are absolutely right. I think I was lucky this time because the screen, custom view and the image I find from resource ID matches perfectly. However as I said, for different resolutioned version of the image is located at drawable folder.